# Read the Excel "defined name" cell values using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, excel

I am reading an Excel file with 80+ columns. Each column has a names intended to the user (to give indication of what is inside). Previously, I was reading this file `openpyxl` and for robustness I was using the command `self.sht.defined_names` to get the column names used by Python.

Since my file is getting larger and larger, it is no longer efficient to use `openpyxl`, so I am switching to `pd.read_excel()`. I checked the pandas documentation and couldn't find the way to do get the Excel defined names with pandas.

**EDIT**

I want to be able to read the name in the top left corner of the Excel file. In the screenshot, I named the cell A1 "Dummy_name", I don't know how to get that value with pandas (or if it is possible).

[image]

Comment: I am talking about something else. I have updated the post accordingly.

Comment: Shame, I would have liked to use the defined name as panda column names. So that the headers in Excel can be modified but the python script still uses the defined name values (which are more difficult to change by mistake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the workbook object with Pandas and get the `defined_names`.

If all your columns have defined names, you can simply set them as your dataframe columns:

```
df = pd.read_excel("excel_file.xlsx", engine="openpyxl")

xls = pd.ExcelFile("excel_file.xlsx")
workbook = xls.book
defined_names = workbook.defined_names

df.columns = list(defined_names)
```

Or you can set only the names that have existing defined names and keep the rest:

```
[...]
df_columns = df.columns
df.columns = list(defined_names) + list(df_columns[len(defined_names) :])
```

Or set the names with defined names and the rest with `''`:

```
[...]
df_columns = df.columns
df.columns = list(defined_names) + [""] * (len(df_columns) - len(defined_names))
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the solution proposed by @e-motta I adapted it to my need, where I sorted the defined name not by alphabetical order (default with panda) but following the column number there are written in:

```
    # Get the sheet index for the DLC preproc
    idx_DLC_sheet = excel_file.sheet_names.index("foo")

    # Load the Excel with panda and openpyxell engine
    worksheet = excel_file.book[excel_file.sheet_names[idx_DLC_sheet]]

    # Get all the existing defined names in the worksheet
    defined_names_temp = worksheet.defined_names

    # Create a dictionary where the key is the column number where the defined name is written and where the value is the defined name itself
    # To ensure only one defined by column, I forced the dictionary creation only if the defined name is found on line 10
    dict_defined_names = {
        worksheet[def_obj.value.split("!")[1]].column: name
        for name, def_obj in defined_names_temp.items()
        if def_obj.value.endswith("$10")
    }

    # Sort the panda series and export to list the values
    self.defined_names = pd.Series(dict_defined_names).sort_index().to_list()
```